# MarkerWithLabel.js: labels wraps after zooming

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

I use Google Maps API with MarkerWithLabel addon in my app. It looks similar as in that example:

```js
// MarkerWithLabel library:

function inherits(e,t){function i(){}i.prototype=t.prototype,e.superClass_=t.prototype,e.prototype=new i,e.prototype.constructor=e}function MarkerLabel_(e,t,i){this.marker_=e,this.handCursorURL_=e.handCursorURL,this.labelDiv_=document.createElement("div"),this.labelDiv_.style.cssText="position: absolute; overflow: hidden;",this.eventDiv_=document.createElement("div"),this.eventDiv_.style.cssText=this.labelDiv_.style.cssText,this.eventDiv_.setAttribute("onselectstart","return false;"),this.eventDiv_.setAttribute("ondragstart","return false;"),this.crossDiv_=MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross(t)}function MarkerWithLabel(e){e=e||{},e.labelContent=e.labelContent||"",e.labelAnchor=e.labelAnchor||new google.maps.Point(0,0),e.labelClass=e.labelClass||"markerLabels",e.labelStyle=e.labelStyle||{},e.labelInBackground=e.labelInBackground||!1,"undefined"==typeof e.labelVisible&&(e.labelVisible=!0),"undefined"==typeof e.raiseOnDrag&&(e.raiseOnDrag=!0),"undefined"==typeof e.clickable&&(e.clickable=!0),"undefined"==typeof e.draggable&&(e.draggable=!1),"undefined"==typeof e.optimized&&(e.optimized=!1),e.crossImage=e.crossImage||"http"+("https:"===document.location.protocol?"s":"")+"://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/drag_cross_67_16.png",e.handCursor=e.handCursor||"http"+("https:"===document.location.protocol?"s":"")+"://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/closedhand_8_8.cur",e.optimized=!1,this.label=new MarkerLabel_(this,e.crossImage,e.handCursor),google.maps.Marker.apply(this,arguments)}inherits(MarkerLabel_,google.maps.OverlayView),MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross=function(e){var t;return"undefined"==typeof MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.crossDiv&&(t=document.createElement("img"),t.style.cssText="position: absolute; z-index: 1000002; display: none;",t.style.marginLeft="-8px",t.style.marginTop="-9px",t.src=e,MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.crossDiv=t),MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.crossDiv},MarkerLabel_.prototype.onAdd=function(){var e,t,i,s,a,r,o,n=this,l=!1,g=!1,p=20,_="url("+this.handCursorURL_+")",h=function(e){e.preventDefault&&e.preventDefault(),e.cancelBubble=!0,e.stopPropagation&&e.stopPropagation()},v=function(){n.marker_.setAnimation(null)};this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.labelDiv_),this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.eventDiv_),"undefined"==typeof MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.processed&&(this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.crossDiv_),MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.processed=!0),this.listeners_=[google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.eventDiv_,"mouseover",function(e){(n.marker_.getDraggable()||n.marker_.getClickable())&&(this.style.cursor="pointer",google.maps.event.trigger(n.marker_,"mouseover",e))}),google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.eventDiv_,"mouseout",function(e){!n.marker_.getDraggable()&&!n.marker_.getClickable()||g||(this.style.cursor=n.marker_.getCursor(),google.maps.event.trigger(n.marker_,"mouseout",e))}),google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.eventDiv_,"mousedown",function(e){g=!1,n.marker_.getDraggable()&&(l=!0,this.style.cursor=_),(n.marker_.getDraggable()||n.marker_.getClickable())&&(google.maps.event.trigger(n.marker_,"mousedown",e),h(e))}),google.maps.event.addDomListener(document,"mouseup",function(t){var i;if(l&&(l=!1,n.eventDiv_.style.cursor="pointer",google.maps.event.trigger(n.marker_,"mouseup",t)),g){if(a){i=n.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(n.marker_.getPosition()),i.y+=p,n.marker_.setPosition(n.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(i));try{n.marker_.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE),setTimeout(v,1406)}catch(r){}}n.crossDiv_.style.display="none",n.marker_.setZIndex(e),s=!0,g=!1,t.latLng=n.marker_.getPosition(),google.maps.event.trigger(n.marker_,"dragend",t)}}),google.maps.event.addListener(n.marker_.getMap(),"mousemove",function(s){var _;l&&(g?(s.latLng=new google.maps.LatLng(s.latLng.lat()-t,s.latLng.lng()-i),_=n.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(s.latLng),a&&(n.crossDiv_.style.left=_.x+"px",n.crossDiv_.style.top=_.y+"px",n.crossDiv_.style.display="",_.y-=p),n.marker_.setPosition(n.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(_)),a&&(n.eventDiv_.style.top=_.y+p+"px"),google.maps.event.trigger(n.marker_,"drag",s)):(t=s.latLng.lat()-n.marker_.getPosition().lat(),i=s.latLng.lng()-n.marker_.getPosition().lng(),e=n.marker_.getZIndex(),r=n.marker_.getPosition(),o=n.marker_.getMap().getCenter(),a=n.marker_.get("raiseOnDrag"),g=!0,n.marker_.setZIndex(1e6),s.latLng=n.marker_.getPosition(),google.maps.event.trigger(n.marker_,"dragstart",s)))}),google.maps.event.addDomListener(document,"keydown",function(e){g&&27===e.keyCode&&(a=!1,n.marker_.setPosition(r),n.marker_.getMap().setCenter(o),google.maps.event.trigger(document,"mouseup",e))}),google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.eventDiv_,"click",function(e){(n.marker_.getDraggable()||n.marker_.getClickable())&&(s?s=!1:(google.maps.event.trigger(n.marker_,"click",e),h(e)))}),google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.eventDiv_,"dblclick",function(e){(n.marker_.getDraggable()||n.marker_.getClickable())&&(google.maps.event.trigger(n.marker_,"dblclick",e),h(e))}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"dragstart",function(e){g||(a=this.get("raiseOnDrag"))}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"drag",function(e){g||a&&(n.setPosition(p),n.labelDiv_.style.zIndex=1e6+(this.get("labelInBackground")?-1:1))}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"dragend",function(e){g||a&&n.setPosition(0)}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"position_changed",function(){n.setPosition()}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"zindex_changed",function(){n.setZIndex()}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"visible_changed",function(){n.setVisible()}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"labelvisible_changed",function(){n.setVisible()}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"title_changed",function(){n.setTitle()}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"labelcontent_changed",function(){n.setContent()}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"labelanchor_changed",function(){n.setAnchor()}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"labelclass_changed",function(){n.setStyles()}),google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_,"labelstyle_changed",function(){n.setStyles()})]},MarkerLabel_.prototype.onRemove=function(){var e;for(this.labelDiv_.parentNode.removeChild(this.labelDiv_),this.eventDiv_.parentNode.removeChild(this.eventDiv_),e=0;e<this.listeners_.length;e++)google.maps.event.removeListener(this.listeners_[e])},MarkerLabel_.prototype.draw=function(){this.setContent(),this.setTitle(),this.setStyles()},MarkerLabel_.prototype.setContent=function(){var e=this.marker_.get("labelContent");"undefined"==typeof e.nodeType?(this.labelDiv_.innerHTML=e,this.eventDiv_.innerHTML=this.labelDiv_.innerHTML):(this.labelDiv_.innerHTML="",this.labelDiv_.appendChild(e),e=e.cloneNode(!0),this.eventDiv_.innerHTML="",this.eventDiv_.appendChild(e))},MarkerLabel_.prototype.setTitle=function(){this.eventDiv_.title=this.marker_.getTitle()||""},MarkerLabel_.prototype.setStyles=function(){var e,t;this.labelDiv_.className=this.marker_.get("labelClass"),this.eventDiv_.className=this.labelDiv_.className,this.labelDiv_.style.cssText="",this.eventDiv_.style.cssText="",t=this.marker_.get("labelStyle");for(e in t)t.hasOwnProperty(e)&&(this.labelDiv_.style[e]=t[e],this.eventDiv_.style[e]=t[e]);this.setMandatoryStyles()},MarkerLabel_.prototype.setMandatoryStyles=function(){this.labelDiv_.style.position="absolute",this.labelDiv_.style.overflow="hidden","undefined"!=typeof this.labelDiv_.style.opacity&&""!==this.labelDiv_.style.opacity&&(this.labelDiv_.style.MsFilter='"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity='+100*this.labelDiv_.style.opacity+')"',this.labelDiv_.style.filter="alpha(opacity="+100*this.labelDiv_.style.opacity+")"),this.eventDiv_.style.position=this.labelDiv_.style.position,this.eventDiv_.style.overflow=this.labelDiv_.style.overflow,this.eventDiv_.style.opacity=.01,this.eventDiv_.style.MsFilter='"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=1)"',this.eventDiv_.style.filter="alpha(opacity=1)",this.setAnchor(),this.setPosition(),this.setVisible()},MarkerLabel_.prototype.setAnchor=function(){var e=this.marker_.get("labelAnchor");this.labelDiv_.style.marginLeft=-e.x+"px",this.labelDiv_.style.marginTop=-e.y+"px",this.eventDiv_.style.marginLeft=-e.x+"px",this.eventDiv_.style.marginTop=-e.y+"px"},MarkerLabel_.prototype.setPosition=function(e){var t=this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.marker_.getPosition());"undefined"==typeof e&&(e=0),this.labelDiv_.style.left=Math.round(t.x)+"px",this.labelDiv_.style.top=Math.round(t.y-e)+"px",this.eventDiv_.style.left=this.labelDiv_.style.left,this.eventDiv_.style.top=this.labelDiv_.style.top,this.setZIndex()},MarkerLabel_.prototype.setZIndex=function(){var e=this.marker_.get("labelInBackground")?-1:1;"undefined"==typeof this.marker_.getZIndex()?(this.labelDiv_.style.zIndex=parseInt(this.labelDiv_.style.top,10)+e,this.eventDiv_.style.zIndex=this.labelDiv_.style.zIndex):(this.labelDiv_.style.zIndex=this.marker_.getZIndex()+e,this.eventDiv_.style.zIndex=this.labelDiv_.style.zIndex)},MarkerLabel_.prototype.setVisible=function(){this.marker_.get("labelVisible")?this.labelDiv_.style.display=this.marker_.getVisible()?"block":"none":this.labelDiv_.style.display="none",this.eventDiv_.style.display=this.labelDiv_.style.display},inherits(MarkerWithLabel,google.maps.Marker),MarkerWithLabel.prototype.setMap=function(e){google.maps.Marker.prototype.setMap.apply(this,arguments),this.label.setMap(e)};

// My code:

function initMap() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.581882,-41.988890);
  var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.581882,-41.988890);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latLng,
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: homeLatLng,
    map: map,
    labelContent: "Blue meetings",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(12, 40),
    labelClass: "map-marker-label",
  });
}
 
initMap();
```

```css
.map-marker-label {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ffba49;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
 <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBJpAMbu-iPZP-prvQjR_YCACH_dheaUGM"></script>
```

At first glance everything looks ok, but sometimes during zooming my label wraps, as we can see here:

[image]

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Comment: I edited my post and hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I found my solution. Problem vanishes when we add `white-space: nowrap;` line to styles of `.map-marker-label`.